# Efficiently combine timestamped sensor data into events in R

Tags: r, time-series, sensors

The underlying dataset is generated by sensors. Each 6 seconds, each sensor sends a signal identifying all the people (who have fobs) in range. Ignoring the people, typical data looks like this:

```
   SensorID   timestamp
     2        2015-08-04 09:56:32
     2        2015-08-04 09:56:38
     2        2015-08-05 18:45:20
     3        2015-08-04 09:54:33
     3        2015-08-04 09:54:39
     3        2015-08-04 09:57:31
     3        2015-08-04 09:58:09
     3        2015-08-04 09:58:15
     3        2015-08-04 09:58:33
     3        2015-08-04 09:58:39
```

I would like to convert this into events with start and end times where consecutive signals from the same sensor (and fob) are considered to be part of the same event if they are less than 60 seconds apart.

So the above test data would be transformed to:

```
SensorID  startTime              endTime              sensorCount   duration
2         2015-08-04 09:56:32    2015-08-04 09:56:38  2             6 secs
2         2015-08-05 18:45:20    2015-08-05 18:45:20  1             0 secs
3         2015-08-04 09:54:33    2015-08-04 09:54:39  2             6 secs
3         2015-08-04 09:57:31    2015-08-04 09:58:39  5             68 secs
```

I have code that works.

```
# identify the ends of sequences
lastKeep <- df$SensorID != df$SensorID[-1L] |
  difftime(df$timestamp[-1L], df$timestamp, units = "secs") > 60

# set startTime and cumulative time and number of signals
df$startTime <- df$timestamp
df$endTime <- df$timestamp
df$sensorCount <- 1

for(jj in 2:nrow(df)) {
 if (lastKeep[jj-1] == FALSE) {
   df$startTime[jj] = df$startTime[jj-1]
   df$sensorCount[jj] = df$sensorCount[jj-1] + 1
 }
}

# select combined records and create duration
df <- df[lastKeep,]
df$duration <- difftime(df$endTime, df$startTime, units = "secs")
df$timestamp <- NULL
```

However, this code takes several seconds for my actual test data of 2000 records and the full dataset is already 6.5 million records and still being collected. I therefore needs something that is efficient.

Is there a way to vectorise this despite its reliance on the 'previous' record to provide the cumulative time and signal count?

My current plan is to use Rcpp, but my C++ skills are mediocre at best. Alternatively, is there an R package that could collapse consecutive signal records? I couldn't find one in the time-series or signal processing world but they are not my fields so I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: You mean less than *6* seconds apart, right?

Comment: Actually 60 because people may move in and out of the sensor range while basically staying in place. The sensors are in a park and are being used for a walking for health program. So I need the code to handle potential gaps in the signal data. Later in the processing I will apply other rules to exclude people driving past and may change the 60 into something else.

Comment: So, why in your last row you grouped together signals within a 68'' time frame if the threshold is 60''?

Comment: @AntoniosK - none of the individual rows differ by >60 seconds, but the whole continuous series start-to-end might be >60 seconds

Comment: Yes, as @thelatemail says, because there were signals in between to link the start and end times together. Each signal in between was no more than 60 seconds later than the previous one.

Comment: Got it. 60'' is the time frame between the consecutive signals. I thought it was the maximum time frame from first to last signal. Cool....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution using the [devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), it should be efficient enough

```
library(data.table) #V 1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp)] # Make sure it's a valid POSIXct class
df[, .(
       startTime = timestamp[1L], 
       endTime = timestamp[.N], 
       sensorCount = .N,  
       duration = difftime(timestamp[.N], timestamp[1L], units = "secs")
      ), 
      by = .(SensorID, 
       cumsum(difftime(timestamp, shift(timestamp, fill = timestamp[1L]), "secs") > 60))]
#    SensorID cumsum           startTime             endTime sensorCount duration
# 1:        2      0 2015-08-04 09:56:32 2015-08-04 09:56:38           2   6 secs
# 2:        2      1 2015-08-05 18:45:20 2015-08-05 18:45:20           1   0 secs
# 3:        3      1 2015-08-04 09:54:33 2015-08-04 09:54:39           2   6 secs
# 4:        3      2 2015-08-04 09:57:31 2015-08-04 09:58:39           5  68 secs
```

---

The idea here is to group by cumulative sum of time differences over 60 seconds within each sensor, then assign the first and last time stamps, the group count, the differences between the first and last time stamps per group.

Comment: I take it V1.9.5 is required for shift since that's the error I got with the production version? I don't really use `data.table` so this will give me a good opportunity to try and understand it.

Comment: Yes, I provided a link in the answer on how to install: `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, yes I just had a problem installing Rtools (apparently Symantec thinks it's malicious) so couldn't immediately access V1.9.5 without some fiddling. Your code is very nice and definitely efficient enough - my 6.5 million records just processed in less than 30 seconds. Now all I just have to do is edit for all the other variables I care about. This has given me the incentive to get across `data.table`, I tend to use dataframes a lot because I mostly work with small datasets and the time cost is worth it for access to the (to me) intuitive syntax of `plyr`.

Comment: I was working on something similar but you're too quick. My only main difference was `duration=as.numeric(difftime(timestamp[.N],timestamp[1L],units="secs")`  and `by=list(SensorID,grp=cumsum(c(0,diff(as.numeric(timestamp)))>60))`

Comment: See my edit. I made a noob mistake and didn't specify `units` explicitly. It should run faster now.

Comment: Thanks, yes now down to 20 secs for the 6.5 million processing (and another 20 secs for creating the DT and converting the POSIXlt to POSIXct)

Comment: What do you mean creating `DT`? Does `setDT(df)` takes 20 seconds? You also don't need to convert `POSIXlt` to `POSIXct`. I only added this line in case you have a character class. Try running this *without* `setDT(df)[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp)]`. Just don't forget to run `setDT(df)` instead of just `df` in the second line. No need to save it anywhere as it is doing it *by reference` so please **don't do** stuff such as `df <- setDT(df)`

Comment: Leaving it as POSIXlt broke it. Got the error `Error in shift(timestamp, fill = timestamp[1L]) : fill must be a vector of length 1.` Note that the code also needs `units = "secs"` instead of just "secs" or it interprets "secs" as a timezone. Further, the timezone error occurred (internally) in a `as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(time1, tz = tz)` call so difftime must be doing a conversion. As difftime is used twice, it is actually quicker to coerce in the separate step.

Answer (score 5):

...and a dplyr (+ lubridate) approach, assuming that dt is the dataset provided above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


dt %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(SensorID) %>%                                                       # for each sensor
  mutate(dist = as.numeric(difftime(timestamp,                                 # create distance between consecutive signals 
                                    lag(timestamp, default=min(timestamp)),           
                                    units = "secs"))) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(dist > 60, 1, 0),                                       # flag distances > 60''
         sessionID = cumsum(flag)+1) %>%                                       # create session id
  group_by(SensorID, sessionID) %>%                                            # for each sensor and session
  summarise(startTime = min(timestamp),                                        # get start, end and counts
            endTime = max(timestamp),
            sensorCount = n()) %>%
  mutate(duration = difftime(endTime, startTime, units="secs")) %>%            # get duration
  ungroup()

#   SensorID sessionID           startTime             endTime sensorCount duration
# 1        2         1 2015-08-04 09:56:32 2015-08-04 09:56:38           2   6 secs
# 2        2         2 2015-08-05 18:45:20 2015-08-05 18:45:20           1   0 secs
# 3        3         1 2015-08-04 09:54:33 2015-08-04 09:54:39           2   6 secs
# 4        3         2 2015-08-04 09:57:31 2015-08-04 09:58:39           5  68 secs
```

Comment: And another excellent answer thanks. The dt version is a little quicker, so I will stick with that as accepted. But this is very efficient with a more familiar syntax.